# VS 2008 compile error for C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have a couple of compile errors which are probably staring at me but I can't seem to resolve them. I've had a go at checking for solutions with the brackets, semi-colons and #includes but no joy. This is in VisualStudio 2008 with C++.

The errors are;

> Error 1   error C2653: 'Game' : is not a class or namespace name  logs.h  34
>
> Error 2   error C3861: 'SetState': identifier not found   logs.h  34

Found here in logs.h

```
Game::SetState(2);
```

Full header;

```
# pragma once

#include "DarkGDK.h"
#include "Screen.h"

class LogS:public Screen
{
    public:
        LogS():Screen()
        {

            //to be added
        }
        void SetBgrnd();
        void Skip();
};

void LogS::SetBgrnd()
{
    s_sprite_id = 1;
    dbShowSprite(11);
    Show();
}

void LogS::Skip()
{
    if(dbReturnKey())
    {
        dbHideAllSprites();
        Game::SetState(2);
    }
}
```

And the Game.h where it should using the static function from;

```
# pragma once

#include "DarkGDK.h"
#include "LogS.h"

class Game
{
    static int gameState;

    public:
        Game();
        static void SetState(int gameState);

};

Game::Game()
{
    LoadImages();
    SetState(1);
}

inline void Game::SetState(gameState& g)
{
    gameState = g;
}
```

Edited out the non-relevant bits. If you can't tell, I'm new to this :P 
Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

static member variables `must` be defined outside class:

```
class Game
{
   static int gameState;

public:
    Game();
    static void SetState(int gameState);

};
int Game::gameState = 0;
```

And as pointed out by @Drew Dormann:

Remove `#include "LogS.h"` from Game.h.

*Game.h doesn't need the definition of `LogS` to compile.*

Add `#include "Game.h"` to LogS.h.

*LogS.h **needs** the definition of `Game` to compile.*

Comment: +1... I need to be somewhere and I see more errors still.  Feel free to add my answer directly to yours.  :)

Comment: @CaptainObvlious sorry, English is not my native language, updated.

Comment: No worries...you give great info.

Comment: Um. **remove** inline ?? Its in a header. It *better* be inlined or defined in the class body. See comment posted on Drew's answer. Sans-inlining, if that header is included in more than one source file you're going to have duplicate symbol errors when linking.

Comment: Thank you for the speedy reply ;)  The reason I had LogS.h included in the Game.h was for creating a LogS object within the Game.h, I guess I have to rethink that.